# Why does getThumbnail function on google apps scripts works inconsistently?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

So, I'm trying open and edit a google presentation, with just one slide, to download it as an image.

To do so, I'm converting it to PDF using mimeType.PFD and then I'm trying to get the thumbnail and save it in a folder.

The thing is that it works sometimes and doens't work others. How can I overcome it?

```
function createJPG() {
  let nome = "Filipe Pereira";
  let grad = "3º Sargento";
  let quadro = "QPMP-C";
  let funcao = "Fotógrafo";
  let lotacao = "Assessoria de Comunicação";
  let telefone = "(27) 3636-8717";
  let email = "secretaria@pm.es.gov.br";
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1EhDglV8aumu__zAOfasdfasrukNKYFDas");
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1fwAhuCdoYyUdHfasdfaPyjRq5iN97");
  const jpgFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("14iZ4sS4jR5sadfasdKainJTnurZ9cgvpH");
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(jpgFolder);
  const tempDocFile = SlidesApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const slide = tempDocFile.getSlides()[0];
  slide.replaceAllText("{nome}",nome);
  slide.replaceAllText("{grad}",grad);  
  slide.replaceAllText("{quadro}",quadro);
  slide.replaceAllText("{funcao}",funcao);
  slide.replaceAllText("{lotacao}",lotacao);
  slide.replaceAllText("{telefone}",telefone);
  slide.replaceAllText("{email}",email);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
    
  //Creates PDF.  
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const newPDF = jpgFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(nome);
  //Try to create IMGE from Thumbnail
  const blob = newPDF.getThumbnail();
  const newJPG = jpgFolder.createFile(blob).setName(nome);
  folder.removeFile(tempFile);
  jpgFolder.removeFile(newPDF);
}
```

The Error message is: *Exception: Argument cannot be null: blob*

I'll really apreciate if someone can illuminate my mind. I'm working to overcome this for over 8 hours now.

Thanks

Comment: It still does not work even if I use the function "Utilities.sleep(10000);"

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar problem, but I believe I've found the solution. I'm converting a Doc file to a PDF instead of a Slides file, but I believe the concept should translate just fine. I believe the new PDF file hasn't completely finished registering with Drive, which is why you receive that `null` error. The way to resolve this is to update the file in Drive before trying to pull that thumbnail. Also, thumbnails are in PNG format, and with this script, I'm just keeping it as that format.

To do this, you need to enable the Drive API on your project. To do this, follow [these instructions to add a new Service to your Google Apps Script project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services):

- Open the Apps Script project.
- At the left, click **Editor < >**.
- At the left, next to **Services**, click **Add a service +**.
- Select Drive API and click **Add**.

Once you do that, you'll be able to use the `Drive` command in your script, which is different than `DriveApp`. I've modified your code below with this addition included:

```
function createJPG() {
  let nome = "Filipe Pereira";
  let grad = "3º Sargento";
  let quadro = "QPMP-C";
  let funcao = "Fotógrafo";
  let lotacao = "Assessoria de Comunicação";
  let telefone = "(27) 3636-8717";
  let email = "secretaria@pm.es.gov.br";
  const docFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1EhDglV8aumu__zAOfasdfasrukNKYFDas");
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1fwAhuCdoYyUdHfasdfaPyjRq5iN97");
  const jpgFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("14iZ4sS4jR5sadfasdKainJTnurZ9cgvpH");
  const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(jpgFolder);
  const tempDocFile = SlidesApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const slide = tempDocFile.getSlides()[0];
  slide.replaceAllText("{nome}",nome);
  slide.replaceAllText("{grad}",grad);  
  slide.replaceAllText("{quadro}",quadro);
  slide.replaceAllText("{funcao}",funcao);
  slide.replaceAllText("{lotacao}",lotacao);
  slide.replaceAllText("{telefone}",telefone);
  slide.replaceAllText("{email}",email);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
    
  //Creates PDF.  
  const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const newPDF = jpgFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(nome);
  //Try to create IMGE from Thumbnail
  const newId = newPDF.getId();
  Drive.Files.update({
    title: newPDF.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.PDF
  }, newId, pdfContentBlob);
  const newPNG = DriveApp.getFileById(newId).getThumbnail().getAs('image/png');
  folder.createFile(newPNG);
  tempFile.setTrashed(true);
  newPDF.setTrashed(true);
}
```

I've tried this a few times, and it is working perfectly for me. I tried changing it to `'image/jpg'` but received an error, so you may need to keep it as a PNG, unless you're able to convert it to a PNG some other way.

Hope this helps!